# Twig complains cannot convert Post to string when doing `{{ post.tags | join(', ') }}`

Tags: twig

I am wondering whats wrong? I have

```
{{ post.tags | join(', ') }}
```

`$post` is a Post object. `$post->getTags()` returns an `array` of tag `string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

`{{ post.tags|join(',') }}` (no space before and after '|' )

if it not work Try

```
{{ set foo='post.tags' }}
{{ foo|join(',') }}
```

Pay attention to the space